How to download NASA SMAP data of a specific region via OPeNDAP?
I am trying to download the rootzone soil moisture data(SPL4SMGP) of a specific region using OPeNDAP. I tried to testing how it worked in the NASA OPeNDAP DAP4 Data Request Form.
But when I tried to request data using this query https://n5eil02u.ecs.nsidc.org/opendap/SMAP/SPL4SMGP.006/2015.03.31/SMAP_L4_SM_gph_20150331T013000_Vv6032_001.h5?dap4.ce=/Geophysical_Data_sm_rootzone[0:462:477][0:2913:2923] I just received 2x2 array data. I am new to this, please help me understand if I am doing something wrong.
Also if there is a better way to download the data of a specific region feel free suggest that as well!
Edit: [FIXED] My query was wrong. The correct url is https://n5eil02u.ecs.nsidc.org/opendap/SMAP/SPL4SMGP.006/2015.03.31/SMAP_L4_SM_gph_20150331T013000_Vv6032_001.h5?dap4.ce=/Geophysical_Data_sm_rootzone[462:1:477][2913:1:2923].

If you answer your own question you can actually add this as an answer in the "Your Answer" box and mark it as the accepted answer - then the system knows it has an answer to your question and that helps the next person struggling with OPeNDAP problems... Better to do that than edit your question and leave the answer empty!

@Spacedman thanks for letting me know, I have added it as an Answer!

My query was wrong. The correct data url is https://n5eil02u.ecs.nsidc.org/opendap/SMAP/SPL4SMGP.006/2015.03.31/SMAP_L4_SM_gph_20150331T013000_Vv6032_001.h5?dap4.ce=/Geophysical_Data_sm_rootzone[462:1:477][2913:1:2923].
